# Using JQuery to horizontally center content within a horizontally scrolling page

Tags: jquery, scroll, position, center

I have a page with 3 content areas (divs with the class "section").

http://refreshperspective.com/CLIENTS/unboxed/products.html

I'm using JQuery to scroll horizontally to these three divs. The issue I am having is keeping the content in the div centered when the window is resized. I have been using the following code:

```
var wind = $(window).width();
$(".section").width(wind);
$(window).resize(function(){
var windRe = $(window).width();
$(".section").width(windRe);
});
```

This works perfectly on the first div that is loaded (the main screen) but fails when you scroll right to another of the three divs.

When these are resized the div moves away from the center (to the right when the window is resized out wider to the right, and vice versa). Any thoughts on how I could get the other two content areas to maintain their centering (should stay inline with the navigation at the bottom that is absolutely positioned) like the first loaded div would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your CSS, you have defined the sections using simple margins.  You'd be much better off using an [elastic CSS layout](http://www.tjkdesign.com/articles/one_html_markup_many_css_layouts.asp) that is designed to deal with window size changes.  Take a look at using

```
margin:0 auto;
```

in your wrapper CSS classes and that should make it easier.  You may also want to consider keeping the three sections in a single div and scrolling that in one big piece.

Nice looking site, btw!

Comment: Trafalmadorian, thanks for the input, unfortunately like you said i believe the fault lies further in the site's positioning and margins. I just can't get those other two content areas to behave like the first one! Thanks for your help, if I don't get it working tonight I think I may just put all the content into a content slider rather than a full horizontal scroll. Probably EasySlider1.7 or something of that nature. Thanks again, when i get the ability to vote for your answer (lacking reputation currently) i will!

Comment: Cool cool, I really appreciate it.  Definitely look into EasySlider, that way you won't have to reinvent the wheel :)

Comment: I ended up moving to a vertical slider to eliminate that issue.
http://refreshperspective.com/CLIENTS/unboxed/products-test2.html

I think the underlying problem actually came from the scroll not reseting to the new center when the window was resized. Thanks for your help though!